# problem in .net framework 3.5 installation

Tags: 13.04

please any one tell which ubuntu version support for .net framework 3.5 with wine and how to install it using wine . i used ubuntu 13.10 version and wine 1.6 version to install .net framework 3.5 but during the installation it gave setup error

Answer (score 0):

You can not install Microsoft .Net framework on Ubuntu.

You can use Cross platform library from [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)